# Change default pagination style in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h4 style="text-align:center;">SHOES</h4>
    @foreach($shoes as $list)
        <div style="margin-top: 40px">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-md-center">
                <div class="card" style="width: 22rem;"> 
                    <img class="card-img-top justify-content-center" src="{{ asset("images/$list->shoe_image") }}" alt="" style="width:350px; height:350px;">
                    {{-- bg-card-pink p-2 m-2 --}}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1>{{ $list->shoe_name }}</h1><br>
                        <h6>{{ $list->shoe_description }}</h6><br>
                        ${{ $list->shoe_price }}<br>
                    </div>
                    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" href="/detail/{{ $list->id }}">
                        SEE DETAILS
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-md-center mt-4">{{ $shoes->links() }}</div>
@endsection
```

Anybody had any idea changing the color/style of the pagination button on the blade?
I use default pagination by laravel which is `$shoes->links()`

Comment: Here `$shoes->links()` method accepts a parameter of custom pagination view file path. check the `links` method here `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination.php`.

Comment: what should i put as the parameter?

Comment: `$shoes->links("your custom pagination view file path")`

Comment: what kind of file should I put? is it a css? can you give example?

Comment: laravel view file

Answer (score 1):

You can customize default pagination by exporting pagination files from vendor folder to resources.

To export run in terminal: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)